# How a website has Amazon Nameserver But hosted in a different Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, web-hosting, cloud-hosting

Take this for Example

[Zomato.com](http://zomato.com)

This site is Hosted by

> NETMAGIC DATACENTER

But the NameServers of this website are as follows.

```
ns-807.awsdns-36.net, ns-1061.awsdns-04.org, ns-1737.awsdns-25.co.uk, ns-496.awsdns-62.com
```

AWS is Amazon Web Service. I knew this already and hence I am asking this question.

I once had a Website with JustHost and the nameservers for the domain should be NS1.JUSTHOST.com. (Hosting Name and NameServers are similar)

But how in the example case the website uses NetMagic Hosting and Amazon NameServers?

Please explain me clearly if any CDN is used or any other thing. I am totally new to this!

Comment: This may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MichaelGardner Sorry i did not know that. Any ways to transfer it there?

Comment: It can be flagged as off topic, and then a moderator can move it.  But it may not be worth it, since you have your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS offers its route 53 domain name service. It doesn't care where the host is - you setup the DNS records and it will point to them.

I happen to have my DNS at AWS route 53 and web server there as well, but you don't have to.

In fact, you can have your domain registered at company 'A', nameservers handled by company 'B' and the website can be at company 'C' - there is no requirement that they are together, and in fact there are lots of good reasons not to put all your eggs in one basket.

http://aws.amazon.com/route53/

Comment: Can you please tell the advantage of doing so? Will it speed up the website?

If so can you suggest Best Hosting Service for a website that performs like PINTEREST / PICCSY (But wont deal much with pictures - we will be dealing more of test data)

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple. Maximum vps hosting provider offer to create custom Nameserver to the user and user can create whatever they want.

For example: Digitalocean.com is a VPS hosting provider and their Nameservers are like, ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2.digitalocean.com, ns3.digitalocean.com, ns4.digitalocean.com

But they offer to create custom Nameserver and you are able to create something like,
ns1.yourname.com, ns-xx.yourname.com

Hope your query is clear now.